# How to know already signed in user in gmail integrated android app

Tags: java, android, gmail-api, google-signin

I am implementing google sign in my android for the first time. I have written code to sign in user form my app, But when user close my app and open it again it ask for sign in. how can i identify that user is already signed in?

below is my code and xml for sign in

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_login"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context="in.thoughtsmith.jobsmith.LoginActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/MessageText"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/Sign_In_Button"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/ProceedWithoutLogIn"
    android:onClick="proceedWithOutLogin"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Logout"
    android:id="@+id/LogoutButton"
    android:onClick="logout"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and activity

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions;
GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
private final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
TextView messageTextView;
SignInButton signInButton;
Button logoutButton;


 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    messageTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MessageText);
    signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.Sign_In_Button);
    signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    logoutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LogoutButton);
    logoutButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, googleSignInOptions)
            .build();


}

 @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.Sign_In_Button:
            Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
            break;
        case R.id.LogoutButton:
            Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(googleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                    messageTextView.setText("SuccessfullyLogout");
                    logoutButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });
            break;
    }
}

  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        hanleSigninIntent(googleSignInResult);
    }
}

public void hanleSigninIntent(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
    if (googleSignInResult.isSuccess()) {
        GoogleSignInAccount userAccount = googleSignInResult.getSignInAccount();
        updateUi(getString(R.string.WelcomeMessage) + " " + userAccount.getDisplayName());
        logoutButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        updateUi(getString(R.string.UserNameOrPasswordWrong));
    }

}


public void updateUi(String message) {
    messageTextView.setText(message);
    messageTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "OnConnectionFailed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
}
```

Comment: Once you signed in and enter to home activity, you would follow some session flag, next you come to your app the session will redirecting your home activity.maybe it will useful for u..

Comment: store some info of user like, username or mob no in your sharedpreference. check this every time you login, if you get null, then there should be login screen, if there is data, then dont display login screen